# Querying SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server-ce

I fully accept that I am ignorant when it comes to SQL Server CE so please forgive me if my question is obvious.

We have a 3rd party product that uses CE in the background to store a history of jobs run.  The tool is only showing the last 30 days of logs, but I wanted to see if what is physically stored is more than what the tool shows us by querying the CE database.  Is it possible to do this?  If so what do I need to be able to query it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/01072b57-f8ae-4453-a9ea-a35a6ea975fa).